# How to select unique row sets from a SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that looks like this

```
StudentId  Subject   Section
1           2          AM
1           3          AM
1           1          AM

2           2          AM
2           3          AM
2           1          AM

3           4          AM
3           2          PM
3           3          PM

4           2          PM
4           3          PM
```

I want to get unique row sets from this table to schedule class rooms. Students with exactly same subjects and sections can go to the same class room. So based on sample data above Student 1 and 2 will go to same class room but not student 3 and 4 since they have different subjects and/or sections.

Student 3 and 4 can not go to same class either although student 4's subject/section combination is a subset of (but not exactly the same) that of student 3.

In other words in order to be in the same classroom, students must have exactly same subjects, same number of subjects and same sections. The output from above sample data should look like this.

```
ClassId   Subject   Section
1           2        AM
1           3        AM
1           1        AM

2           4        AM
2           2        PM
2           3        PM

3           2        PM
3           3        PM
```

The table I am dealing with has 10 million rows but there are only 200 unique row sets. The select statement can ignore the StudentId and can replace it with a dynamically generated ClassId. I can then use this select statement to insert unique row sets into class table.

Comment: *"How do I do it?"* = No effort. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your description is not clear to me. Especially this part is confusing: "*The select statement can ignore the `StudentId` and can replace it with a dynamically generated `ClassId`.*" If you do not know which students belong to which class, what would you do with this data?

Comment: This is a simplified version of the problem I am working on. The classid being generated will be added as a foreign key back to student table.

Comment: Did either of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 0):

So I took your top table and wrote the following dynamic query to generate a list of classrooms.  This will give you the exact output as the second table.

```
declare @subjects varchar(max)
set nocount on
select
    @subjects = coalesce(@subjects,'') + 
          quotename(cast(subject as varchar(25))) + ','
from
    [student]
group by
    Subject

set @subjects = substring(@subjects,0,len(@subjects))
declare @dyn_sql varchar(max)

set @dyn_sql = 
'
select
    class_room,
    subject,
    section
from
    (
select
    row_number() over (order by '+@subjects+') as class_room,
    '+@subjects+',
    count(distinct studentid) as total_students
from
    (
    SELECT 
        studentId,
        cast(subject as varchar(25)) as subject,
        section
    FROM [student]
    ) as d1
pivot (max(section) for subject in ('+@subjects+')) as d2
group by
'+@subjects + '
) as d1
unpivot(section for subject in  ('+@subjects+')) as d2
'

exec (@dyn_sql)
print (@dyn_sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

This has the queries to populate the class table and the joining table between studentID and classID...

(Note: Run the commented out logic first to populate the temp table)

```
/*
Create  Table testData (StudentID Int, [Subject] Int, Section Varchar(2))

Insert  testData
Select  1,2,'AM'
Union   All
Select  1,3,'AM'
Union   All
Select  1,1,'AM'
Union   All
Select  2,2,'AM'
Union   All
Select  2,3,'AM'
Union   All
Select  2,1,'AM'
Union   All
Select  3,4,'AM'
Union   All
Select  3,2,'PM'
Union   All
Select  3,3,'PM'
Union   All
Select  4,2,'PM'
Union   All
Select  4,3,'PM';
*/

--      Get class info
If      Object_ID('tempdb..#classes') Is Not Null Drop Table #classes;

With    studentClasses As
(
        Select  t.StudentID,
                Replace((   Select Convert(Varchar(10),[Subject])+'_'+Section As 'data()'
                            From    #testData t2
                            Where   t.studentID = t2.studentID
                            Order   By Section,[Subject]
                            For     Xml Path('X')), ' ', ',') As classes
        From    #testData t
        Group   By t.studentID
),      classIDs As
(
        Select  Row_Number() Over (Order By classes) As classID,
                Convert(XML,classes) As classes
        From   (Select  Distinct classes
                From    studentClasses) sc
),      breakOutClasses As
(
        Select  Row_Number() Over (Partition By cID,classID Order By classID) As nID,
                n.cID,
                n.classID,
                t.split
        From   (Select  Row_Number() Over (Partition By classID Order By classID) As cID,
                        classID,
                        Convert(Xml,'<X>'+Replace(t2.split,'_','</X><X>')+'</X>') As firstBreak
                From    classIDs c
                Cross   Apply  (Select  colData.D.value('.','Varchar(50)') As split
                                From    c.classes.nodes('X') As colData(D)) t2) n
        Cross   Apply  (Select  colData.D.value('.','Varchar(50)') As split
                        From    n.firstBreak.nodes('X') As colData(D)) As t                 
)
Select  b1.classID, b1.split As [Subject], b2.split As Section Into #classes
From    breakOutClasses b1
Join    breakOutClasses b2
        On  b1.classID = b2.classID
        And b1.cID = b2.cID
        And b1.nID = 1
        And b2.nID = 2
Order   By classID, Section, [Subject];


If      Object_ID('tempdb..#studentClassID') Is Not Null Drop Table #studentClassID;

With    students As
(
        Select  t.StudentID,
                Replace((   Select Convert(Varchar(10),[Subject])+'_'+Section As 'data()'
                            From    #testData t2
                            Where   t.studentID = t2.studentID
                            Order   By Section,[Subject]
                            For     Xml Path('')), ' ', ',') As classes
        From    #testData t
        Group   By t.studentID
),      classes As
(
        Select  t.classID,
                Replace((   Select Convert(Varchar(10),[Subject])+'_'+Section As 'data()'
                            From    #classes t2
                            Where   t.classID = t2.classID
                            Order   By Section,[Subject]
                            For     Xml Path('')), ' ', ',') As classes
        From    #classes t
        Group   By t.classID
)
Select  c.classID, s.studentID Into #studentClassID
From    classes c
Join    students s
        On  c.classes = s.classes;


Select  *
From    #classes;

Select  *
From    #studentClassID;
```